# Best way to send message from controller to view in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net core mvc (latest version).

I always send my messages (success or failed messages) from controller to view by TempData like this:

```
TempData["msg"] = "Operation was successful";
```

and in the view show this message to user:

```
@if (TempData["msg"] != null)
    {
        string msg = (string)TempData["msg"];
        <script>
            UIkit.notification({ message: '@msg', status: 'primary', pos: 'bottom-center', timeout: 15000 });
        </script>
    }
```

i want to know the standard (best and optimized) way to pass this kind of messages from controller to view.

is TempData good for this case? is there any better way?

Thanks.

Comment: In MVC you are creating a view in controller, so you can pass any value to the view as a parameter. `return View("Operation was successful")`

Comment: @Fabio
if i pass some data as model to view, your answer is not work

Comment: Why not have the message as a property in the model class itself?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya
because in this case i have to make view model for every view

Comment: In MVC model is what view is going to display. Model is not the object which represents some database table, but view represents the data it given from controller. - So this is a way to work - other ways is possible but they will be just a workarounds which is more difficult to maintain than one "model" object with data to display.

Comment: _if i pass some data as model to view_ - exactly the message is part of the data you are passing to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Create a model to represent all data you are going to display in the view.

```
public class NewInvoiceViewData
{
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool HasMessage => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message) == false;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> CreateInvoice(NewInvoiceParameters parameters)
{
    var invoice = createInvoice.From(parameters);
    var message = invoice == null ? "Something gone wrong" : "Success";
    
    var viewData = new NewInvoiceViewData
    {
        Invoice = invoice,
        Message = message
    }

    return View(viewData);
}
```

In view

```
@if (@data.HasMessage)
{
    <script>
        UIkit.notification({ message: '@data.Message', status: 'primary', pos: 'bottom-center', timeout: 15000 });
    </script>
}
```

MVC(Model View Controller) is not about application layering. Model isn't required to be a business objects or database tables. Notice, that it can be a business object or database datable if no extra values are required, but it is not mandatory.

Model is an object which view know how to display without extra workarounds and model can have all data required and possible prepared for the view.

Answer (score 1):

You usually send a "Model" to your "View" through "Controller" that's what MVC stands for of course:

```
public class SendMessageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //... More stuff
}

//... inside controller
var model = new SendMessageModel()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Name"
};

return View(model);

//... inside view
@model SendMessageModel


<span>@Model.Id @Model.Name</span>
```

but sometimes you need to send additional info to the view. This data is not necessarily part of the model. For this kind of scenario using ViewData is my choice.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(bool? error)
{
    if (error == true)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Some error message";
    }

    //....
    return View();
}

//... inside view
@model SendMessageModel
@{
    var msg = ViewData["Message"];
}

@if(msg != null)
{
    <span class="error">@msg</span>
}
```

of course, this is not the only way or "the best way". There's always another way to do this and that's the beauty of Asp.Net Core or programming in general.